# how to create a dummy node and set it to NULL?

Tags: adt

I am trying to create dummy node in my createList() function, however everytime I run the program, it results in a segmentation fault. Here is my code so far for createList();

```
node*createList()
{
    node*dummyNode; 

    dummyNode->next = NULL;

    return dummyNode; 
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language? What compiler, OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
node*dummyNode;
```

creates a local variable that lives only inside your function createList. After the method is left, the variable is freed. I assume you use C or C++, thus you have to allocate memory with `malloc`

```
node*dummyNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
```